# Blackjack game doesnt work

Tags: python-3.x, blackjack

```
import random
deckOfCards = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
playerHand = []
computerHand = []


def testWin():
    if sum(playerHand) == sum(computerHand):
        print("Draw")
    elif sum(playerHand) == 21:
        print("Blackjack! You win")
    elif sum(computerHand) == 21:
        print("Computer has blackjack you lose")

    if sum(playerHand) > 21:
        if sum(computerHand) < 21:
            print("You lost")
        elif sum(computerHand) > 21:
            print("Draw")
    elif sum(computerHand) > 21:
        if sum(playerHand) < 21:
            print("You win")
        elif sum(playerHand) > 21:
            print("Draw")
    elif sum(playerHand) < 21:
        if sum(computerHand) > 21:
            print("You win!")
        elif sum(computerHand) < 21 and sum(computerHand) < sum(playerHand):
            print("You win")
        elif sum(computerHand) < 21 and sum(computerHand) > sum(computerHand):
            print("You lose")


def drawPlayerCard():
        playerHand.append(deckOfCards[random.randint(0, 9)])
        print("Your Cards are:", playerHand)
        print("total:", sum(playerHand), "\n")
        if len(playerHand) < 2:
            drawPlayerCard()
        drawComputerHand()


def drawComputerHand():
    if sum(computerHand) <= 17:
        computerHand.append(deckOfCards[random.randint(0, 9)])
        print("the computer has:", computerHand)
        print("total:", sum(computerHand), "\n")
        if len(computerHand) < 2:
            drawComputerHand()
        hitStand()
    else:
        print("the computer stands with a total of:", sum(computerHand))
        hitStand()


def hitStand():
        option = input("do you want to hit or stand? [h/s]")
        if option.lower() == "h":
            drawPlayerCard()
        elif option.lower() == "s":
            testWin()
        else:
            print("please say if you want to hit or stand!")
            hitStand()


def start():
    startGaming = input("Do you want to play Blackjack? [y/n]")
    if startGaming == "y":
        drawPlayerCard()
    elif startGaming == "n":
        pass
    else:
        print("please state if you want to start the game")
        start()


start()
```

Hey, i'm kinda new to pyhton and i tried to create a simple blackjack game. it doesn't entirely work as intended. when i do stand i get an never ending loop of "do you want to hit or stand? [h/s]" or things like this

```
do you want to hit or stand? [h/s]h
Your Cards are: [10, 2, 4]
total: 16 

the computer has: [9, 6, 4]
total: 19 

do you want to hit or stand? [h/s]s
Your Cards are: [10, 2, 4, 3]
total: 19 

Draw
do you want to hit or stand? [h/s]s
Your Cards are: [10, 2, 4, 3, 4]
total: 23 

You lost
the computer stands with a total of: 19
do you want to hit or stand? [h/s]s
Your Cards are: [10, 2, 4, 3, 4, 2]
total: 25 

You lost
```

before the code stops and i cant figure out why it does this. it gives a loop of do you want to hit or stand, until it suddenly stops and suddenly adds another card without me hitting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that "drawPlayerCard()" calls "drawComputerHand()" and "drawComputerHand()" calls "hitStand()".

**Explanation:**

first problem in "drawPlayerHand()":

```
    if len(playerHand) < 2:
        drawPlayerCard()
    drawComputerHand()
```

When your if statement is true, "drawPlayerHand()" is executed a second time. This means that "drawComputerHand()" is also executed 2 times.

And you have the same problem in "drawComputerHand()":

```
    if len(computerHand) < 2:
        drawComputerHand()
    hitStand()
```

Try to fix it yourself. If you arent able to fix it, I can post some more code.

Comment: thank you i added an else statement before drawComputerHand() and HitStand() that way it works. thank you so much i didnt see the problem.